# Are eye disorders more common in wind instrument players?

Tags: brass, health, woodwinds

I played the clarinet for 12 years (from 9 to 21), and occasionally I practiced for hours a day. Out of curiosity I read that eye pressure increases temporarily during play. 
Those who are professional players, do you think wind instrument players have more issues with their eyes?

Comment: You'd have to ask Squinty & Bog-Eye, but right now they're on a gig with Picky the guitarist & the drummer, Thumbs.  *[sorry, couldn't resist] ;)*

Comment: It's probably more true that drumming makes you go deaf...

Comment: @tim WHAT!?!?!?

Comment: @Tim I thought it was deaf people became drummers :-)

Comment: Please post a link to that allegation.  We really don't like responding to random claims from the fog of the internet.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10647731
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/49755064_Intraocular_pressure_fluctuations_in_professional_brass_and_woodwind_musicians_during_common_playing_conditions
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10958606

Answer (score 1):

I've spent nearly 50 years in the company of 'blowers' and can't say it's ever been an issue.  We could probably get the 'Daily Mail' to run a scare story.   (That's our British sensationalist newspaper, specialising in patriotic racism and  'Badgers give you cancer' scares. Sorta like Fox News?)

Comment: The plural of "anecdote" is not "data."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - true. The plural of 'an ecdote' is 'several ecdotes'...

Comment: But a complete absence of anecdotes is of interest.

Comment: Actually, the original quote was from Raymond Wolfinger who is on record with "I said 'The plural of anecdote is data' some time in the 1969-70 academic year while teaching a graduate seminar at Stanford" - and it morphed into the opposite from there.

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed glaucoma after 2 years of bass clarinet playing (2-4 hours daily).  My ophthalmologist discovered it, has been keeping watch on it, and checked references.  Conclusion: no connection. Instruments with possible links to eye pressure, according to her, are trumpet played a la Louis Armstrong, and bagpipes.